# How to Edit JSON data displaying what i want

Tags: php, laravel

[image: Click for image]

Here I am displaying my JSON.  What is the best way for me to go through the data and display ID and Seat_name for each at the same time?

this is the output i am looking for

[image]

Comment: The best way to go through data in an array? A loop?

Comment: The best way to go through data in an array? JS?

Comment: You can't return twice in the same function. The 2nd `return` will never be called.

Comment: `foreach ( $availableSeat as $seat ) { var_dump( $seat ); if ( $seat['id'] == 3 ){ echo $seat['seat_neighborhood']; } }`

Comment: Edit and post your **codes** & **output** instead of picture. And post also your desire output

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton yes I know I cant return twice, I just return the first time to view the data.  Yes a loop because  i want to learn how to loop through all the data to change all to just display ID and seat_name, because then I'm going to pass the variable to JS

Comment: @STA im sorry new to this, i am not sure how too.

Comment: I answered your question, if it helped dont accept is as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `select` method to select specific column data :

```
$availableSeat = Seat::select('id', 'seat_name')->where('status', 0)->get();
```

Or, you can do with on `get()` method as like :

```
$availableSeat = Seat::where('status', 0)->get(['id','seat_name']);
```